# Invalid mex-file, libarmadillo, cannot open shared object file

Tags: matlab, shared-libraries, mex, armadillo

I know there are a lot of posts about the topic, this might be a duplicate, but I don't think so. My config is: Matlab R2014b, clang 3.4, Ubuntu 14.04, armadillo-4.600.4.

I have a local install (not system-wise, so including/linking manually) of Armadillo that works fine when outside of Matlab.
I'm trying to run a Mex file using Armadillo from Matlab. It compiles fine using the command (truncated for short):

```
mex -compatibleArrayDims -outdir +mx -L/home/john/.local/arma/lib -larmadillo -I/home/john/.local/arma/include test_arma.cpp
```

Problem is when I try to run it I get this error:

```
Error using mx.test_arma
Invalid MEX-file '/path/to/+mx/test_arma.mexa64': libarmadillo.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` echoed from the shell that started Matlab contains `/home/john/.local/arma/lib` (where `libarmadillo.so` is), and I also manually added this path within Matlab using `setenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH',...)`. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I don't have a link now, but MATLAB is funny about `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  Perhaps try a symlink first. Also, are you sure the dependency you added to the path is 64-bit.  I don't know Ubuntu's folder structure.

Comment: @chappjc Your comment about 64-bits is interesting, I'm going to double check everything, and recompile my shared libraries from scratch to make sure there is no mismatch, because as I said I'm getting segfaults now, and I'm fairly confident it's not from the code itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found out how to *run* it. Now it's segfaulting :/ And I'm fairly confident it's not the code itself, because I can compile and run the exact same code outside Matlab. I'll try to find out what's wrong, and if it's relevant, I'll post my adventures here later on.

For the *running* problem; it seems that Matlab uses the variable `LD_RUN_PATH` for loading shared libraries at runtime. Appending my path `... /.local/arma/lib` to `LD_RUN_PATH` using `setenv` did the trick in my case. Cheers for your comments/answers!

**Update:** I finally solved this, the problem was due to an expected word-size mismatch (32/64 bits, ie `int32_t` vs. `int64_t`) between Matlab's BLAS/LAPACK libraries and Armadillo's calls. There are two solutions that I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421934/armadillo-matlab-mex-segfault).

Comment: Ah! I'll have to finally remember the `LD_RUN_PATH` variable. I knew there was something different about the MATLAB environment, but I rarely use Linux... +1 BTW, why `-compatibleArrayDims`?

Comment: @chappjc The new versions of Matlab enable `-largeArrayDims` (or something like this) by default for mex, which essentially define `mwSize` as `uint64_t`. I'm using my own library which itself uses Armadillo, and I'm using `uint32_t` throughout for now. `compatibleArrayDims` is just a way to revert to the "old way", and make Matlab use 32 and not 64 bits for indexing :) (note to myself: this might be the cause of my segfaults, if for some reason this also causes Mex to expect 32 bits libraries..)

Comment: So you use unsigned 32-bit indexes, got it.  But I think you mean `unsigned long long` is 64 bits.  ;)

Comment: Argh you were too fast :) Yes, I just corrected it, thanks a lot!