# Armadillo + Matlab Mex segfault

Tags: matlab, segmentation-fault, lapack, blas, armadillo

I fiddled with this the whole day, so I thought I might make everyone benefit from my experience, please see my answer below.

I first had a problem with running a compiled Mex file within Matlab, because Matlab complained that it couldn't open the shared library `libarmadillo`. I [solved this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28408156/invalid-mex-file-libarmadillo-cannot-open-shared-object-file) using the environment variables `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LD_RUN_PATH` (`DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LYLD_RUN_PATH` in osx).

The problem remained however, that a simple test file would segfault at runtime even though the exact same code would compile and run fine outside Matlab (not Mex'd).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The segfault seems to be caused by the fact that Matlab uses 64bits integers (`long long` or `int64_t`) in its bundled LAPACK and BLAS libraries. Armadillo on the other hand, uses 32bits integers (regular `int` on a 64bits platform, or `int32_t`) by default.

There are two solutions; the first one involves forcing Matlab to link to the system's libraries instead (which use `int`s), the second involves changing Armadillo's config file to enable `long long`s with BLAS. I tend to think that the first is more reliable, because there is no black-box effect, but it's also more troublesome, because you need to manually install and remember the path of your BLAS and LAPACK libs.

Both solutions required that I stopped using Armadillo's shared libraries and linked/included manually the sources.
To do this, you must simply install LAPACK and BLAS on your system (if they are not already there, in Ubuntu that's `libblas-dev` and `liblapack-dev`), and copy the entire `includes` directory somewhere sensible like in `$HOME/.local/arma` for example.

---

### Solution 1: linking to system's libraries

From the matlab console, set the environment variables `BLAS_VERSION` and `LAPACK_VERSION` to point to your system's libraries. In my case (Ubuntu 14.04, Matlab R2014b):

```
setenv('BLAS_VERSION','/usr/lib/libblas.so');
setenv('LAPACK_VERSION','/usr/lib/liblapack.so');
```

You can then compile normally:

```
mex -compatibleArrayDims -outdir +mx -L/home/john/.local/arma -llapack -lblas -I/home/john/.local/arma test_arma.cpp
```

or if you define the flag `ARMA_64BIT_WORD` in `includes/armadillo_bits/config.hpp`, you can drop the option `-compatibleArrayDims`.

---

### Solution 2: changing Armadillo's config

The second solution involves uncommenting the flag `ARMA_BLAS_LONG_LONG` in Armadillo's config file `includes/armadillo_bits/config.hpp`. Matlab will link to its bundled LAPACK and BLAS libraries, but this time Armadillo won't segfault because it's using the right word-size. Same than before, you can also uncomment `ARMA_64BIT_WORD` if you want to drop the `-compatibleArrayDims`.

Comment: This is not correct: "uses 32bits version [of LAPACK] by default".  You're confusing two separate issues: size of integers (32 and 64 bit), and the instruction set (x86/ia32 vs x86-64). They are related, but not the same thing.  Armadillo will by default use `int` for internal integer variables, which on most systems is 32 bit (even on x86-64 Linux). Defining `ARMA_64BIT_WORD` just forces the internal integers to be 64 bits. Some LAPACK implementations (like MATLAB's) have this as their default, some don't (even if they are compiled for x86-64 systems).

Comment: @mtall Sorry if you found this confusing, and thank you for pointing this out; as I said though, `ARMA_64BIT_WORD` is just to get rid of the `-compatibleArrayDims`, it _doesn't_ fix the segfault. Regarding the target architecture, I can't explain the segfault if it is not a 32/64 bits mismatch, and [it has been suggested somewhere else](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/113845/). But I would be most grateful if you could share a more detailed explanation of what you think is really happening behind the scene.

Comment: The LAPACK that comes with Matlab may not have the same ABI as standard LAPACK, probably due to different integer widths.  Standard LAPACK uses `int` (even on 64 bit machines), while it looks like Matlab's LAPACK uses `long long`. Enabling `ARMA_BLAS_LONG_LONG` causes Armadillo to use 64 bit integers when passing data to BLAS and LAPACK functions.

Answer (score 0):

Compiled with

```
mex -larmadillo -DARMA_BLAS_LONG_LONG armaMex_demo2.cpp
```

(In Matlab)

```
armaMex_demo2(rand(1))
```

works without segfault.

However, compiled with

```
mex -larmadillo  armaMex_demo2.cpp
```

(In Matlab)

```
armaMex_demo2(rand(1))
```

causes a segfault.

Here, armaMex_demo2.cpp is

```
/* ******************************************************************* */
// armaMex_demo2.cpp: Modified from armaMex_demo.cpp copyright Conrad Sanderson and George Yammine.
/* ******************************************************************* */
// Demonstration of how to connect Armadillo with Matlab mex functions.
// Version 0.2
// 
// Copyright (C) 2014 George Yammine
// Copyright (C) 2014 Conrad Sanderson
// 
// This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
// License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this
// file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/.
/////////////////////////////
#include "armaMex.hpp"


void
mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) {
  /* 
     Input:   X (real matrix)
     Output:  Eigenvalues of X X.T
  */


  if (nrhs != 1)
    mexErrMsgTxt("Incorrect number of input arguments.");


  // Check matrix is real
  if( (mxGetClassID(prhs[0]) != mxDOUBLE_CLASS) || mxIsComplex(prhs[0]))
    mexErrMsgTxt("Input must be double and not complex.");


  // Create matrix X from the first argument.
  arma::mat X = armaGetPr(prhs[0],true);


  // Run an arma function  (eig_sym)
  arma::vec eigvals(X.n_rows);
  if(not arma::eig_sym(eigvals, X*X.t()))
    mexErrMsgTxt("arma::eig_sym failed.");    


  // return result to matlab
  plhs[0] = armaCreateMxMatrix(eigvals.n_elem, 1);
  armaSetPr(plhs[0], eigvals);

  return;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer? What symbol do you define and why is it important? What else does it do? Is there a bug report for this you could link to?

Comment: @tar Did you intend to write an answer? How is that different from the second solution currently proposed? Why did you include the source of the compiled file?