# Invalid MEX-file libmkl_rt.so: cannot open

Tags: c++, matlab, ubuntu, mex

I have a MEX-file that compiles and runs perfectly on CentOS 7.7 and MATLAB R2018b. I can compile it on Ubuntu 16.04 with MATLAB R2016b, but when I try to run it I get

> libmkl_rt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

I have tried

```
setenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH',[getenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH'),':/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.1.144/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin'])
```

and

```
setenv('LD_RUN_PATH',[getenv('LD_RUN_PATH'),':/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.1.144/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin'])
```

As per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28408156/invalid-mex-file-libarmadillo-cannot-open-shared-object-file), with no luck. Still the same issue.

This is the command I use to compile:

```
mex -v -I/usr/include -I/opt/intel/mkl/include station_cov.cpp -L/lib64 -larmadillo -L/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64 -lmkl_core -lmkl_sequential
```

It seems as though it is a path issue but I just can not figure out where I am going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

```
./station_cov.mexa64: /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./station_cov.mexa64)
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff1f5ca000)
libarmadillo.so.9 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libarmadillo.so.9 (0x00007fb5f7592000)
libmwlapack.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwlapack.so (0x00007fb5f71e3000)
libmwblas.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwblas.so (0x00007fb5f6fc7000)
libmx.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmx.so (0x00007fb5f6c3a000)
libmex.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmex.so (0x00007fb5f6a02000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fb5f66f0000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/sys/os/glnxa64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fb5f64da000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb5f6110000)
libmkl_rt.so => not found
libarpack.so.2 => /usr/lib/libarpack.so.2 (0x00007fb5f5ec5000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fb5f5bbb000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055b58a794000)
libut.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libut.so (0x00007fb5f58fc000)
libmwbinder.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwbinder.so (0x00007fb5f56e8000)
libmwompwrapper.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwompwrapper.so (0x00007fb5f54e2000)
libboost_system.so.1.56.0 => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libboost_system.so.1.56.0 (0x00007fb5f52df000)
libmwcpp11compat.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwcpp11compat.so (0x00007fb5f50c0000)
libtbb.so.2 => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libtbb.so.2 (0x00007fb5f4e75000)
libtbbmalloc.so.2 => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libtbbmalloc.so.2 (0x00007fb5f4c23000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fb5f4a05000)
libmwresource_core.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwresource_core.so (0x00007fb5f4803000)
libmwi18n.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwi18n.so (0x00007fb5f44d9000)
libmwfl.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwfl.so (0x00007fb5f4128000)
libboost_chrono.so.1.56.0 => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libboost_chrono.so.1.56.0 (0x00007fb5f3f22000)
libboost_date_time.so.1.56.0 => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libboost_date_time.so.1.56.0 (0x00007fb5f3d10000)
libboost_filesystem.so.1.56.0 => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libboost_filesystem.so.1.56.0 (0x00007fb5f3afa000)
libboost_log.so.1.56.0 => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libboost_log.so.1.56.0 (0x00007fb5f381d000)
libboost_regex.so.1.56.0 => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libboost_regex.so.1.56.0 (0x00007fb5f350c000)
libboost_signals.so.1.56.0 => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libboost_signals.so.1.56.0 (0x00007fb5f32f6000)
libboost_thread.so.1.56.0 => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libboost_thread.so.1.56.0 (0x00007fb5f30d5000)
libicudata.so.56 => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libicudata.so.56 (0x00007fb5f16ef000)
libicuuc.so.56 => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libicuuc.so.56 (0x00007fb5f1358000)
libicui18n.so.56 => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libicui18n.so.56 (0x00007fb5f0ede000)
libicuio.so.56 => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libicuio.so.56 (0x00007fb5f0cd0000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fb5f0ab6000)
libmwservices.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwservices.so (0x00007fb5f0483000)
libmwmpath.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmpath.so (0x00007fb5f01f5000)
libmwm_dispatcher.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so (0x00007fb5efefb000)
libmwmlutil.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmlutil.so (0x00007fb5ef6d9000)
liblapack.so.3 => /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3 (0x00007fb5eeef6000)
libblas.so.3 => /usr/lib/libblas.so.3 (0x00007fb5eec94000)
libgfortran.so.3 => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/sys/os/glnxa64/libgfortran.so.3 (0x00007fb5ee976000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fb5ee76e000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fb5ee569000)
libexpat.so.1 => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007fb5ee341000)
libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007fb5ee108000)
libboost_serialization.so.1.56.0 => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libboost_serialization.so.1.56.0 (0x00007fb5edea8000)
libunwind.so.8 => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libunwind.so.8 (0x00007fb5edc88000)
libssl.so.1.0.0 => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fb5eda1d000)
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fb5ed5c2000)
libmwdisplay_device.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwdisplay_device.so (0x00007fb5ed3ba000)
libmwcppmicroservices.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwcppmicroservices.so (0x00007fb5ed1b8000)
libmwregexp.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwregexp.so (0x00007fb5ecf6f000)
libmwsettingscore.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwsettingscore.so (0x00007fb5ecb2a000)
libmwms.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwms.so (0x00007fb5ec4e6000)
libmwnativedisplay.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwnativedisplay.so (0x00007fb5ec2db000)
libmwopccore.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwopccore.so (0x00007fb5ec084000)
libmwopcmodel.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwopcmodel.so (0x00007fb5ebe09000)
libmwopczippackage.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwopczippackage.so (0x00007fb5ebbe5000)
libmwopcmwservices.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwopcmwservices.so (0x00007fb5eb985000)
libmwwebproxy.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwwebproxy.so (0x00007fb5eb778000)
libmwkeybrd.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwkeybrd.so (0x00007fb5eb575000)
libboost_iostreams.so.1.56.0 => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libboost_iostreams.so.1.56.0 (0x00007fb5eb361000)
libCppMicroServices.so.2.1.0 => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libCppMicroServices.so.2.1.0 (0x00007fb5eb0cc000)
libPocoCrypto.so.31 => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libPocoCrypto.so.31 (0x00007fb5eaeaa000)
libPocoFoundation.so.31 => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libPocoFoundation.so.31 (0x00007fb5eaac8000)
libPocoJSON.so.31 => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libPocoJSON.so.31 (0x00007fb5ea87a000)
libPocoNet.so.31 => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libPocoNet.so.31 (0x00007fb5ea55a000)
libPocoNetSSL.so.31 => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libPocoNetSSL.so.31 (0x00007fb5ea313000)
libPocoUtil.so.31 => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libPocoUtil.so.31 (0x00007fb5ea0a0000)
libPocoXML.so.31 => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libPocoXML.so.31 (0x00007fb5e9e13000)
libxerces-c-3.1.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libxerces-c-3.1.so (0x00007fb5e977c000)
libmwflnetwork.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwflnetwork.so (0x00007fb5e94d2000)
libmwflstoragevfs.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwflstoragevfs.so (0x00007fb5e921b000)
libmwflstorageprovider.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwflstorageprovider.so (0x00007fb5e8fe1000)
libmwstoragefileprovider.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwstoragefileprovider.so (0x00007fb5e8da8000)
libmwstorageshlibstoragesys.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwstorageshlibstoragesys.so (0x00007fb5e8b65000)
libmwstoragefilefolderobserver.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwstoragefilefolderobserver.so (0x00007fb5e8951000)
libmwsearch_path_interfaces.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwsearch_path_interfaces.so (0x00007fb5e8745000)
libmwxmlcore.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwxmlcore.so (0x00007fb5e84cf000)
libopenblas.so.0 => /usr/lib/libopenblas.so.0 (0x00007fb5e643b000)
libquadmath.so.0 => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/sys/os/glnxa64/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00007fb5e61fd000)
libminizip.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libminizip.so (0x00007fb5e5ff0000)
libmwflcrypto.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwflcrypto.so (0x00007fb5e5dc3000)
libmwflcryptoutils.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwflcryptoutils.so (0x00007fb5e5bb7000)
libmwflcryptocryptopp.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwflcryptocryptopp.so (0x00007fb5e5667000)
libmwflstorageevents.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwflstorageevents.so (0x00007fb5e5460000)
libmwstoragesharedlib.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwstoragesharedlib.so (0x00007fb5e5243000)
libmwflcryptoopenssl.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwflcryptoopenssl.so (0x00007fb5e5019000)
```

Comment: You need to set your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before starting MATLAB. If you modify it with `setenv` within MATLAB, it affects child processes of MATLAB, but not the MATLAB process itself. You can set it in a shell, then you must start MATLAB from that same shell. You can also change your `.bashrc` file (assuming you use Bash, other shells have different files).

Comment: I have added it to  .bashrc with no luck

    LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.1.144/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin"

Comment: Did you the start MATLAB from a new Bash shell?

Comment: Another problem could be a mix of 32 and 64-bit binaries. Try running `ldd mexfile.mexa64` from a shell.

Comment: I added the output from ldd station_cov.mexa64. it says libmkl_rt.so is not found as well as libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of MATLAB [requires GCC 4.9.x](https://www.mathworks.com/content/dam/mathworks/mathworks-dot-com/support/sysreq/files/SystemRequirements-Release2016b_SupportedCompilers.pdf) for compiling MEX-files. You likely [have version 5.3 instead](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gcc).

When compiling with version 5.3, your binary needs to link to the C++ library that comes with version 5.3, or a newer one.

MATLAB is compiled with 4.9, and needs that version of the C++ library, or a newer one.

MATLAB carries its own version of the GCC C++ library (v 4.9), and links to it way before your MEX-files is loaded. When your MEX-file is linked in, there’s already a version of the C++ library loaded, but it’s the wrong version.

There are two ways of fixing this:

- The official way: Install GCC 4.9.x, and make sure you use it when compiling your MEX-file by adding appropriate arguments to the `mex` command. You will have to recompile your dependencies too (Armadillo and the MKL, which seem to depend on a host of other libraries judging from your `ldd` output).
- The bad way: Delete the C++ libs from the MATLAB directory and have it use the ones that come with the system (which are newer and therefore this should work). We’re talking about the files `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6` and `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/sys/os/glnxa64/libgcc_s.so.1`. This solution is sooooo much easier than the other one, I cannot recommend anything else. I have done this with many different versions of Linux and MATLAB in the past,  but likely not with Ubuntu 16 and MATLAB R2016a, so try it out carefully by moving the files away or renaming them, so you can undo the change if MATLAB won’t boot. This does however require admin rights, so it’s not a viable solution for everyone.

Comment: That second option worked perfectly though in the future, I think I will go with the first option. Thank you!